React native managing permissions
Is there a way to determine which permissions are not used and are safe to remove in the info.plist and AndroidManifest?

Review your JavaScript code:

Examine your project's JavaScript files for any instances where you're using libraries or APIs that require specific permissions. For example, if you're not using geolocation features, you likely don't need the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.

Check your native modules:
If you're using any third-party native modules, check their documentation to understand what permissions they require.

Use tools:
react-native-permissions: This library can help you check the status of permissions at runtime. You can use it to identify permissions that are granted but never actually used in your app.

Modify your AndroidManifest.xml:


Remove unused permissions:
Once you've identified permissions that are not required, open your android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml file and remove the corresponding  tags.
Use tools:node="remove":
To remove permissions that might be included by third-party libraries, use the tools:node="remove" attribute like this:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="remove" />
Common permissions that can often be removed:

READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: Not required if you're not accessing files on the device's storage.
WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: Not required if you're not writing files to the device's storage.
READ_PHONE_STATE: Not required unless you specifically need to access the device's phone state.
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION: Not required if you're not using geolocation features.

Be careful:
Removing permissions can break your app's functionality if those permissions are actually needed.
Privacy:
Respect user privacy. Only request permissions that are truly necessary for your app's functionality.
